# LWP is not following redirections

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp

when I try to access Google I get the error message `302 Found`

Here is the code

```
use parent qw(LWP::UserAgent);

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self  = {};
  bless $self, $class;

  $self->agent("Mozilla/8.0");
  $self->timeout(20);

  return $self;
}

sub gethtml {
  my ($self, $url) = @_;

  my $response = $self->get($url);

  $response->is_success ?
      $response->decoded_content :
      $response->status_line;
}

1;
```

test.pl :

```
my $spider = Spider->new;
say $spider->gethtml('http://www.google.com/');
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I have used LWP without problems for a while

Answer (score 3):

When you subclass a module and want to overload one of the methods it is more than likely that you need to execute the base class's method *first*, and then add some tweaks of your own. You can do this using the `SUPER` pseudo-class, which allows you to call a method from the base class.

Your `Spider` module isn't doing the necessary `LWP::UserAgent` initialisation at all, so your `$self` is just a reference to an empty hash. It should look like this

```
package Spider;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'LWP::UserAgent';

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);

  $self->agent('Mozilla/8.0');
  $self->timeout(20);

  $self;
}

sub gethtml {
  my ($self, $url) = @_;

  my $response = $self->get($url);

  $response->is_success ?
      $response->decoded_content :
      $response->status_line;
}

1;
```

By the way, you should take care not to suck bandwidth out of site that are meant to be accessed manually. Be nice, and especially take care to abide by the `robots.txt` file that says how the site may be accessed by a spider program. You should take a look at [`LWP::RobotUA`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::RobotUA) which has been written expressly for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The last I heard `LWP::UserAgent` doesn't follow 300-style redirects by default.

Try using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize). It is much better suited for crawling the web and you have much more control of it.

Comment: By default [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent) supports up to seven redirections for `GET` and `HEAD` requests. These defaults can be changed at run time.